# What Are Charge Profile and Charge Accuracy?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

In Power Statistics Window, selecting Laptop Battery from left menu, then going statistics tab, we have "Charge Profile", "Charge Accuracy", "Discharge Profile", "Discharge Accuracy" graph types.

What do those 4 graph types indicate? For example, is it good or bad to have high values?

(Power Statistics Window can be reached by clicking on battery icon right top corner of screen, then clicking on the top menu item.)

Answer (score 2):

My best guess:
'Charge Profile' is the difference between the predicted charge and actual charge

'Charge Accuracy' is the percent off how correct how long it took to get the cell charge was (or possibility the predicted charge (time and how much is being charged) versus the actual reported charge).

As for the case of Discharge, I believe it's the same as above but flipped to pertain to discharging.